# Continuously do something on jstree using mousedown

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, jstree, mousedown

How can I modify the code below to continually scroll the objects when mouse is on hold? This code is fine with clicks.

```html
.on("click.jstree", ".down-arrow", $.proxy(function (e) {
 var obj = this.get_element(e.target);            
 obj["page_num"] += 1;
 obj["arrow"] = true;
 this.draw_next(obj);
}, this))
```

I tried using mousedown.jstree and setInterval() but it didn't worked.

```html
.on("mousedown.jstree", ".down-arrow", $.proxy(function (e) {
         var interval;
         interval = setInterval (function () {
         var obj = this.get_element(e.target);  
         obj["page_num"] += 1;
         obj["arrow"] = true;
         this.draw_next(obj);
          }, 50);
        }, this))
.on("mouseup", ".down-arrow", $.proxy(function (e)) {
       clearInterval(interval);
}, this))
```

Comment: please include html and/or css in the snippet

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag, then use a `while()` loop to keep doing whatever you need to do. Then eventually set the flag back to false!

```
// set a flag
var mouseIsDown = false;

// create function to do "stuff" when mouse is down
function mouseDownAction(){
  while(mouseIsDown){
    // do some code
  }
}

// set event listener to set flag to true and fire function
$(some_selector).on('mousedown', function(){
  mouseIsDown = true; 
  mouseDownAction(); 
});

// change flag to false on mouseup
$(some_selector).on('mouseup',function(){ mouseIsDown = false; });
```